# Mastering dto polimorphism

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, dto, solid-principles

I mentioned that I haven't worked a lot with DTO's. Im playing around with polimophism on DataTransfereObjects. I could not figure out a nice Solution, so i have made this codesample to master polimorphism with DataTransfereObjects and different logic implementation, Uses Polimorphism, generics, interfaces, abstract and so on.

Please check the code. HINT me whats bad, could be done better or easier. Check accessmodifier, Also check against SOLID (think I haven't understood it correctly). At the end it seems to be too complex, is it common to solve it in that way?

Actually, I try to call some (de)serialize programlogic which uses baseDto for derived dtos without loosing their specific information. This Code should be a clean abstraction sandbox for problems of that kind.

```
void Main()
{
    var twoIngrDto = new TwoIngredientsDto();
    var threeIngrDto = new ThreeIngredientsDto(); 

    var twoIngrMulAnswerChecker = new TwoIngredientsMultiplicationAnswerChecker();
    var threeIngrAddAnswerChecker = new ThreeIngredientsAdditionAnswerChecker();

    twoIngrMulAnswerChecker.IsTheAnswerCheckImplementationTheAnswer(twoIngrDto); //TRUE .Dump();
    threeIngrAddAnswerChecker.IsTheAnswerCheckImplementationTheAnswer(threeIngrDto); //TRUE .Dump();
    twoIngrMulAnswerChecker.IsTheAnswerCheckImplementationTheAnswer(threeIngrDto); //FALSE .Dump();

    IAnswerCheck answerchecker = new IngredientsAnswerChecker();
    answerchecker.CheckAnswer(twoIngrMulAnswerChecker, twoIngrDto); //TRUE .Dump();
    answerchecker.CheckAnswer(threeIngrAddAnswerChecker, threeIngrDto); //TRUE .Dump();

    /// QUESTION: How can I use the answerchecker 'twoIngrMulAnswerChecker' with the derived DTO 'threeIngrDto'
    /// It failes with following error:
    /// The type 'UserQuery.TwoIngredientsMultiplicationAnswerChecker' cannot be used as 
    /// type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'UserQuery.IngredientsAnswerChecker.CheckAnswer<T,DTO>(T, DTO)'. 
    /// There is no implicit reference conversion from 'UserQuery.TwoIngredientsMultiplicationAnswerChecker' 
    /// to 'UserQuery.TheAnswerChecker<UserQuery.ThreeIngredientsDto>'.
    //answerchecker.CheckAnswer(twoIngrMulAnswerChecker, threeIngrDto).Dump();
    answerchecker.CheckAnswer(twoIngrMulAnswerChecker, (TwoIngredientsDto)threeIngrDto).Dump(); // is casting the solution? 
}

interface IAnswerCheck
{
    bool CheckAnswer<T, DTO>(T answerCkecker, DTO ingredientsDto) 
        where T : TheAnswerChecker<DTO>
        where DTO : IngredientDto;
}

public abstract class TheAnswerChecker<T> where T : IngredientDto
{
    internal abstract int TheAnswerCheckImplementation(T answerIngredietsDto);
    private int TheAnswer {get { return 42;} }

    public bool IsTheAnswerCheckImplementationTheAnswer(T answerIngredietsDto)
    {
        return TheAnswer == TheAnswerCheckImplementation(answerIngredietsDto);
    }
}

//generate a base class
public class IngredientsAnswerChecker : IAnswerCheck //: TheAnswerChecker<IngredientDto>
{
    public bool CheckAnswer<T, DTO>(T answerCkecker, DTO ingredientsDto) 
        where T : TheAnswerChecker<DTO>
        where DTO : IngredientDto
    {
        return answerCkecker.IsTheAnswerCheckImplementationTheAnswer(ingredientsDto);
    }
}

public class TwoIngredientsMultiplicationAnswerChecker : TheAnswerChecker<TwoIngredientsDto>
{
    internal override int TheAnswerCheckImplementation(TwoIngredientsDto answerIngredietsDto) //where T : TwoIngredientsDto
    { 
        return answerIngredietsDto.A * answerIngredietsDto.B;
    }
}

public class ThreeIngredientsAdditionAnswerChecker : TheAnswerChecker<ThreeIngredientsDto>
{
    internal override int TheAnswerCheckImplementation(ThreeIngredientsDto answerIngredietsDto)
    {
        return answerIngredietsDto.A + answerIngredietsDto.B + answerIngredietsDto.C;
    }
}

public class IngredientDto
{
    public IngredientDto()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
}

public class TwoIngredientsDto : IngredientDto
{
    public virtual int A {get {return 6;}}
    public virtual int B {get {return 7;}} 
}

public class ThreeIngredientsDto : TwoIngredientsDto
{
    public override int B {get {return 24;}} 
    public int C {get {return 12;}} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind DTOs is to use dummy/plain objects for data transfer, therefore you should avoid adding complexity, for example through inheritance, to this kind of objects, otherwise DTOs will loose their main purpose of being simple and serialization friendly.

Regarding your "cast question", the answer is yes, a cast will permit to use ThreeIngredientsDto instead of TwoIngredientsDto.

For the private property "TheAnswer" I would suggest to use a const.

Overall your example respects SOLID principles, but beware not always we have to split our code in atomic pieces for achieving Single Responsibility Principle. For example instead of having **TwoIngredientsMultiplicationAnswerChecker**, **ThreeIngredientsAdditionAnswerChecker** and **TheAnswerChecker** classes, I would use a single class **TheAnswerChecker** which would have an overload method for each type of DTO, in this way your code will be more readable and more understandable and after all, your class responsibility will be only to check the answer. Of course, if the logic for checking the answer for each type of DTO will be very complex and will require a large amount of code, then probably it will make sense to split in different classes. The point is that **SOLID** should represent a set of principles to keep in mind when you structure your code, but sometimes breaking some of the rules can bring many benefits, in which case you should do this compromise.